# If else Statement in <%= raw {} %> ERB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, if-statement, erb

I have something like this:

```
<%= raw query.inline_columns.map {|column| 
   "<td class=\"#{column.css_classes}\">#{column_content(column, issue)} </td>"
}.join %>
```

I want to add a if else Statement when the css.classes == "assigned_to" how can i do that ?

I tried this but don't work

```
<%= raw query.inline_columns.map {|column|
    <% if #{column.css_classes} == "assigned_to" %>
        "<td class=\"#{column.css_classes}\">#{column_content(column, issue)} </td>"
    <% else %>
         "<td class=\"#{column.css_classes}\">#{column_content(column, issue)}  TEST TEST  </td>"
    <% end %>
}.join %>
```

I'm a beginner in ERB language sorry.

Thank's for help

Comment: Can you explain (in an EDIT to your question, not a comment) what `raw_query` is, and what you get back from `raw query.inline_columns`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you need the final result to be one string?  Because if not, it should be simpler to just return the html for each `inline_columns`, like:

```
<% query.inline_columns.each do|column| %>
  <% if column.css_classes == "assigned_to" %>
    <td class="<%= column.css_classes %>"> <%= column_content(column, issue) %> </td>
  <% else %>
    <td class="<%= column.css_classes %>"> <%= column_content(column, issue) %> TEST TEST  </td>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```